# Чтение куска файла в двумерный массив

Tags: файлы, c++

Здравствуйте! Есть файл типа:

```
00000
11100
00000
```

Как оптимально считать из этого файла лишь кусок? Например только:

```
1110
0000
```

Мне нужно обрабатывать большие файлы, причем нужный кусок может быть где угодно. Как это сделать?

Comment: А как Вы определяете, где находится нужный кусок? Есть готовое смещение или по номеру строки? Или, может, читаете последовательно и определяете, что вот оно.

Comment: Есть переменные x и y. По ним и ищу кусокю

Comment: @egordorichev, длина строк фиксирована?

Comment: Нет. Файл постоянно изменяет свой размер, но координаты все равно остаются известными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fseek](http://cppstudio.com/post/1628/)
Вот такая функция есть, при чтении файла ей можно пользоваться.

Comment: А нет ли функции, чтоб на какое-то кол-во строк указатель вниз перемещала?

Comment: Вы сами легко можете написать ее, используя лишь `fgetc()` и подсчитывая число `\n`.

Comment: Нет, такой нет. @avp верно написал, можно реализовать это самостоятельно, просмотрел все символы перевода строки и записал их индексы в массив. Таким образом, подставляя значения из этого массива в fseek, вы сможете перемещаться к нужной строке.